# How to bind events for new elements?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable

How can I register an event for new elements programmatically? I'm using AutoComplete library and Data Table library (add row function) and the autocomplete event is only applied on the existing rows but not for new inserted rows. How can I fix that? Please help...

This is what I've tried...

```
$('#addRow').on('click', function () {

        let input = document.createElement("input")
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.setAttribute("class", "material_no");
        input.setAttribute("id", "material_no");
        input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter material no.");

        table.row.add( [
            '-',
            `
            <input type='text' class='material_no' id = 'material_no' placeholder = 'Enter Material No.'/>
            `,
            '-',
            '-',
            '-',
            '-',
            '-',
            '-',
            '-',
            '-',
            '-',
        ] ).draw();
 
        counter++;
    } );
    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#addRow').click();

    //autocomplete library
    $('.material_no').each(function(i, e) {
        $(this).bind('change').autocomplete({
            source: '/mef/suggestions.php',
            change: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log($(this).val())

                console.log(table.row($(this).parent()).index())
                
                
                return false;
            },
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting event inside the `draw` function in datatable. I don't know if it is good approach or can cause bugs in the future...

```
table.on('draw', function () {
        $('.material_no').each(function(i, e) {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: '/mef/suggestions.php',
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                    console.log($(this).val())

                    console.log(table.row($(this).parent()).index())
                    

                    // $.ajax({
                    //     url: '/mef/ajax/part_names.php',
                    //     method: 'POST',
                    //     data: { part_code: $(this).val()},
                    //     success: data => {
                    //         $(`td:eq(${i})`).html(data)
                    //         console.log(data)
                    //     },
                    //     error: err => console.log(err)
                    // })
                    
                    
                    return false;
                },
            })
        })
    });
```